# How to style the selected item of a ListBox to look like a selected item of a ListView (with GridView)?

Tags: wpf, listview, listbox, styles

I'd like to have the selected item of a ListBox on the right to look like the selected item of a ListView (with GridView) on the left.

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8427/xamlpad.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8427/xamlpad.png)

This is the XAML code:

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ListView Margin="4" Width="200" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Site" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListViewItem>Server Fault</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Stack Overflow</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Super User</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
        <ListBox Margin="4" Width="200">
            <ListBoxItem>Server Fault</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Stack Overflow</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Super User</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Margin="4" Content="OK" Width="80" Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a simple article](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/customizing-the-selected-item-in-a-listbox/) that shows you how to apply a template to the selected item of a list box. Actually getting the look right may be fiddly, but it looks like a border with slightly rounded corners and a vertical gradient, both easy to achieve in XMAL.

Of course you could apply the same template to both lists, that way they will definitely look identical.